# View Containment ContainerView / Fragment Support in Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is there a way in Xamarin.Forms to handle view containment?  Let's say I want to build a vertical TabBar with a container. Normally in iOS I'd utilize a Container View and in Android I'd use Fragments.  How would I do this in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I want to achieve something similar but not by using tabs. I want to have multiple `ContentPage`s on the screen at the same time (like `Fragment`s in Àndroid`).

Comment: No, I ended up moving away from Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms has a TabbedPage Setting the title of the sub pages populates the tabs with their text.

```
public class MyTabbedPage: TabbedPage
{
    public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        var firstPage = new MyFirstPage
        {
            Title = "My First Page"
        };
        var secondPage = new MySecondPage
        {
            Title = "My Second Page"
        };
        Title = "Title of my Tabbed Page";
        Children.Add(firstPage);
        Children.Add(secondPage);
    }

}
```